# How to do Dynamic property naming in NIfi?

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt, nifi-processor

I'm in a situation where I need to be able to set the name of a property using Expression Language. Is there any way to do that?

I try to create an attribute using an UpdateAttribute processor and put in ${property1} as the property name. Now, property1 is in reference to an existing attribute containing the value "property2". What I'd hope is that the flowfile has a new property added named "property2" but what I end up with is a new property literally named "${property1}".

Is this even possible?
How to do this using JOlt Spec?

Answer (score 2):

you can use ExecuteGroovyScript

```js
def ff=session.get()
if(!ff)return

ff[ff.property1] = ff.property2

REL_SUCCESS<<ff
```

or ExecuteScript with Javascript language

```
var ff = session.get();
if (ff != null) {
    var k = ff.getAttribute( 'property1' );
    var v = ff.getAttribute( 'property2' );
    ff = session.putAttribute( ff, k, v );
    session.transfer( ff, REL_SUCCESS );
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I need it to be in ECMAScript or JavaScript

Comment: why it could not be groovy? :) it's simpler

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use Expression Language to dynamically set the property name of an UpdateAttribute processor directly.

Here's a workaround, use:

1. **AttributesToJSON** - to convert the attributes to a JSON object.
2. **JoltTransformJSON** to manipulate the JSON object using Jolt Specification.
3. **JSONToAttributes** to convert the JSON object back to attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You can gather the literal `property2` as `prop : property2` key-value pair within a JSON using a **`JoltTransformJSON`** processor along with a such specification

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "prop":"${property1}" // yields "prop" : "property2"
    }
  }
]
```

possibly added an **`UpdateAttribute`** processor stated previously in the flow with

*`property name - value`* : **`property1 - property2`**

Comment: But arent we manually assigning here in Update Attribute as you have mentioned here property name - value : property1 - property2

Comment: I dont want to assign manually